# Angular meta tag information does not show in google

Tags: html, angularjs, seo, search-engine, google-search

I have angular base application [yuppi.com.ua](http://yuppi.com.ua) and I am using meta directive to bind content description for all pages using following code:

```
 <meta ng-if="meta.description != undefined" name="description" 
       content="{{meta.description}}" />
```

When I inspect code I see that generated HTML contains exect what I need:

```
 <meta class="ng-scope" content="Yuppi - самая большая в Украине доска бесплатных объявлений" 
       name="description" ng-if="meta.description == undefined"/>
```

But when I search my site in Google, I see some text from footer but there should content description from . is anybody know what is wrong

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google will [choose your search results](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35624#3) snippets from the following places (not necessarily in this order):

1. The page's Meta Description tag
2. The page's Open Directory Project (ODP) Listing
3. Page content relevant to the search query

This means that just because you have a meta description tag doesn't mean Google is going to use it.